# Missing Buttons and Function on Ribbon bar

Tags: ribbon

The ribbon in my entire production SP2010 farm is not right and am not sure how it got like that (am assuming a web part deployed and maybe did something?? As I am NOT a developer and did not do anything with customizing/extending the ribbon beyond a few minor css changes.)

In any case, I am missing on the editing tab, Insert Audio/Video and the Insert Hyperlink is just insert link and does not provide the split button feature so no "From SharePoint" or "From Address" options. :( This sucks. Any ideas on how I can get the ribbon back to its normal function? (FYI: I do have a development environment and it is NOT like that, however, EVERY site on the production farm is - so am assuming it is a global change that occurred??)

thoughts or ideas would be greatly appreciated!!

~KZ

Comment: How did you make your CSS changes?

Answer (score 1):

From the information given in your question I can only think of two different scenarios:

1. You created a custom css-file which hide certain elements in the ribbon, and you need to customize your masterpage and remove the link to your custom css-file, or unhide the hidden ribbon elements. This can be done in SharePoint Designer or Visual Studio.
2. You have customized tha original css-file, hidden elements in the ribbon and can't get the old css back. But there is a solution to this problem if you follow the guide of [Kyle Schaeffer: SharePoint 2010 CSS Reset](http://kyleschaeffer.com/sharepoint/css-reset/).

Comment: Hi, while I agree those could be possibles, it's farm-wide and I already attempted an OOTB css, master page and page layout thus eliminating that it is any of those things.  I then proceeded to copy my master page, page layout, and css to my development farm, and it does not impact the functions of the ribbon. So I am left to think that something changed on the server but am trying to determine what. I looked at the CMDUI.XML file and it seems to be like the original on my dev server. Is there files on the server that would possibly control the ribbon elements?

Comment: @Kath And you have the sema effect on both user and admin accounts?

Comment: Yeup / I am looked on as SCA and I have users who are just 'owners' of the site(s) and no change :(

Comment: Is there any way to take files that control the ribbon from one server and copy them to another to give me a full "reset" of the ribbon?